# Group by and count foreign key

Tags: django, django-models

I have a data model where I store certain `Event`s that happen. Each `Event` is linked to an `EventType`. The data model roughly looks like this:

```
class EventType(models.Model):
    name = ...

class Event(models.Model):
    date = ...
    event_type = models.ForeignKey(EventType)
```

What I would like to know is how often each event time appeared. I tried it like this:

```
Event.objects.values('event_type', count=Count('event_type'))
```

But the result looks like this:

```
<QuerySet [{'count': 1, 'event_type': 71}, {'count': 1, 'event_type': 2}, {'count': 1, 'event_type': 71}, {'count': 1, 'event_type': 71}, ...
```

So the entries did not get grouped. How can I make it such that they are grouped?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query
`Event.objects.all().values('event_type').annotate(count=Count('event_type'))`